# How to use dynamic array in java Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, dynamic, average

I tried to create a program using the Java programming language that can calculate the average of the input using object-oriented programming concepts. When I use a static array of programs runs fine, but when I tried to set the array is dynamically program gets an error. How do I set array dynamically using an object-oriented programming concepts ?.

This is the **program with static array** :

```
public class Avg {

private int n;

 private int[] value = new int[3];

public int getN() {
    return n;
}

public void setN(int n) {
    this.n = n;
}

public int getValue(int number) {
    return this.value[number];
}

public void setValue(int number, int value) {
    this.value[number] = value;
}        

public double getAverage(){
    int i = 0;
    double total = 0;
    for(i=0;i<getN();i++){
        total = total+value[i];
    }
    return (total/getN());
}

   public double getAverage(){
    int i = 0;
    double total = 0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        total = total+value[i];
    }
    return (total/3);
    }

import java.util.*;
public class driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Avg klas = new Avg();
    int i,number = 0, value = 0;        
    Scanner prak = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the number of sequence :");        
    int n = prak.nextInt();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println("sequence of : " + (i+1));                 
            System.out.println("enter the value : ");                                
             value = prak.nextInt();
    }
    klas.setValue(number, value);  
    System.out.println(klas.getAverage());
}
}
```

and this is **program using dynamic array** :

```
public class Avg {            
private int n;

private int[] value = new int[getN()];


public int getN() {
    return n;
}

public void setN(int n) {
    this.n = n;
}

public int getValue(int number) {
    return this.value[number];
}

public void setValue(int number, int value) {
    this.value[number] = value;
}        

public double getAverage(){
    int i = 0;
    double total = 0;
    for(i=0;i<getN();i++){
        total = total+value[i];
    }
    return (total/getN());
} 

import java.util.*;
public class driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Avg klas = new Avg();
    int i,number = 0, value = 0;        
    Scanner prak = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the number of sequence :");
    klas.setN(prak.nextInt());         
    for(i=0;i<klas.getN();i++){
            System.out.println("sequence of : " + (i+1));                 
            System.out.println("enter the value : ");                                
             value = prak.nextInt();
    }
    klas.setValue(number, value);  
    System.out.println(klas.getAverage());
}
}
```

when i run the program use dynamic array i got this *error* :

```
enter the number of sequence :
2
sequence of : 1
enter the value : 
4
sequence of : 2
enter the value : 
5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
            at wksenin.Avg.setValue(Avg.java:31)
            at wksenin.driver.main(driver.java:26)
    Java Result: 1
```

but when using static array the program running well :

```
enter the number of sequence :
3
sequence of : 1
enter the value : 
4
sequence of : 2
enter the value : 
5
sequence of : 3
enter the value : 
3
1.0
```

> how to use dynamic array in java OOP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to initialize the `value` array after you initialize `n`.
You can do that like this:

```
private int[] value;

public void setN(int n) {
   this.n = n;
   values = new int[n];
}
```

A safer way of doing this is to define a constructor which accepts the `n` value as a parameter.

```
private int[] value;

public Avg(int n){
   this.n = n;
   values = new int[n];
}
```

Comment: it works ! thanks Titus. but, can i ask question to you how to get the average value of the input. i use this function before but it not return the average value :      public int getAverage(){
  int i = 0;
  int total = 0;
  for(i=0;i<getN();i++){
     total = getValue(i) + getValue(i);
  }
  return (total/getN());
 }  and how i get the average of the value ? is my function wrong ?

Comment: @MuhammadFadliFaturzaman Since the `value` array size can be something other then `3`, in the `getAverage()` method, you should replace `3` with `value.length`.

Comment: @MuhammadFadliFaturzaman it should be ` total = total + getValue(i);` instead of ` total = getValue(i) + getValue(i);`

Comment: done,but still not return the average the value 'public int getAverage(){
        int i = 1;
        int total = 0;
        for(i=0;i<value.length;i++){
           total = total + getValue(i);                   
        }
        return (total/value.length);
    }' this function just count base the last loop :'enter the number of sequence :
2
sequence of : 1
enter the value : 
4
sequence of : 2
enter the value : 
4
2'

Comment: @MuhammadFadliFaturzaman You need to move this `klas.setValue(number, value);` inside the `for` loop (at the end) and change it to `klas.setValue(i, value);`

Comment: it works, thank you @titus !. i really appreciate your help :) .